# How do I dynamically load tinymce editors in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have searched a lot and found many answers to this question, but none of them seem to work for me.

I am making a WordPress plugin. When you go to add/edit a page/post there is a new metabox with 2 buttons. One is for deleting editors that have been created, which works just fine. The other allows you to create new editors through a bit of jquery and PHP. The issue here is that the HTML created by wp_editor is being created and added to the page just fine, however tinymce never takes effect. I understand that it is probably because scripts need to be re-initiated and such, but no solution I have come across has fixed this issue.

Here is the PHP used to generate the editor HTML.

```
    $blocks = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_mbp-blocks', true );
    $id = sanitize_title( $name );

    $box_html = "";

    if( ! is_array( $blocks ) )
        $blocks = array();

    $blocks[ $id ] = array(
        'name' => $name, 
        'type' => 'editor'
    );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_mbp-blocks', $blocks );

    $box_html .= '<div id="block_'.$id.'">';
    $box_html .= '<p><input id="checked_mbp" type="checkbox" name="checked_mbp[]" value="'.$id.'"><strong>' . $name . '</strong></p>';

    ob_start();
    wp_editor( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_mbp-' . $id, true ), 'editor_' . $id );
    $box_html .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $box_html .= '</div>';

    $return_array = array("html" => $box_html, "editorid" => $id);

    return json_encode($return_array);
```

And this is the JavaScript used, minus any of the fixes I have tried.

```
    jQuery( function( $ ) {

$('#addblock').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var blockname = $("#blockname").val();
    var blockpostid = $("#blockpostid").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.casinovault.com/wp-content/plugins/blockpages/ajax_functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'name': blockname, 'action': 'register', 'post_id': blockpostid },
        success: function(result){

             $('#mbp_blocks').append(result['html']);
        }

     });         

});

$('#deleteblock').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var blockpostid = $("#blockpostid").val();

    confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the checked blocks?');

    var checked_mbp = $('#checked_mbp:checked').map(function(i,n) {
        return $(n).val();
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.casinovault.com/wp-content/plugins/blockpages/ajax_functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'action': 'delete', 'delete_mbp[]': checked_mbp, 'post_id': blockpostid },
        success: function(result){
            var checked = result.split(',');
            $.each(checked, function() {
                $('#block_'+this).remove();
            });
        }

     });         

});
```

});

I have been trying to get this to work by adding fixes to ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a little more complex as I had to dynamically load form whenever user click on the edit button of an item.

Use the following code if you have id.

```
function editorFix( qtid )
{
    if ( typeof quicktags !== 'undefined' ) {

        try 
        {
            if ( typeof QTags.instances[qtId] !== 'undefined' )
            {
                QTags.instances = {};
                tinymce.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, qtId );
            }

            quicktags( tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit[qtId] );

            if ( ! window.wpActiveEditor ) {
                window.wpActiveEditor = qtId;
            }

            switchEditors.go(qtId, 'html');
        } catch(e){};
    }
}
```

In case you don't have an ID or want to show multiple editors

```
function editorFix()
{
    if ( typeof quicktags !== 'undefined' ) {
        for ( var qtId in tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit )
        {
            try 
            {
                if ( typeof QTags.instances[qtId] !== 'undefined' )
                {
                    QTags.instances = {};
                    tinymce.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, qtId );
                }

                quicktags( tinyMCEPreInit.qtInit[qtId] );

                if ( ! window.wpActiveEditor ) {
                    window.wpActiveEditor = qtId;
                }

                // Wordpress Switch Editor
                switchEditors.go(qtId, 'html');
            } catch(e){};
        }
    }
}
```